# how to fetch Large sharepoint list item(>10000) and write them in text file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

My SharePoint site having a Large List that contains large data
I have to fetch all items and show them in gridview?
I am using below code and getting the below error

**"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator"**

```
private void GetData()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("URL"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("BulkData");

                if (list != null)
                {
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /></IsNotNull></Where>";
                    query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
                    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                    int itemCount = items.Count;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    string str1 = string.Empty;
                    foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                    {
                        int i = 1;
                        sb.Append("\r\n").Append(Convert.ToString(item["Title"])).Append("\r\n");
                        i++;
                    }
                    Log(sb);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

## region Log File

```
    public void Log(StringBuilder ErrorMessage)
    {

        string LogFileTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
        string LogFilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\\Logs\");
        if (!File.Exists(LogFilePath + "BulkData" + LogFileTime + ".txt"))
        {
            var LogFileName = File.Create(LogFilePath + "BulkData" + LogFileTime + ".txt");
            var WriteToLogFile = new StreamWriter(LogFileName);
            WriteToLogFile.Write(ErrorMessage);
            WriteToLogFile.Close();
            LogFileName.Close();
        }


    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the **List View threshold** in Central Admin, setup by default to 5000 elements.

To minimize database contention, SQL Server often uses row-level locking as a strategy to ensure accurate updates without adversely impacting other users who are accessing other rows.

However, if a read or write database operation, such as a query, causes more than 5,000 rows to be locked at once, then it's more efficient for SQL Server to temporarily escalate the lock to the entire table until the database operation is completed.

[image]

See this link on [MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010378155.aspx)

See this link for [instructions step-by-step](http://sharepointknowhow.blogspot.it/2013/04/how-to-change-list-view-threshold-limit.html)

However if you must change this value by code you can

```
SPQuery q1 = new SPQuery();
q1.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
```

Caution! Remember to grant privileges to the account that will run the code.

see [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinaayoub/archive/2010/04/27/programmatically-using-the-object-model-override-for-the-list-view-threshold.aspx) for details.

Comment: I have to handle it Programmatically

Comment: @vishalgoyal have you see my updated answer using `SPQueryThrottleOption` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SPQuery.RowLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.rowlimit(v=office.15).aspx) to specify the number of items to be fetched. (The MSDN link also has an example of loading limited number of items in multiple pages)

Answer (score 0):

You may use two different approaches:

1. [ContentIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.utilities.contentiterator(v=office.15).aspx) object - is not available in SharePoint
   Foundation
2. [SPWeb.ProcessBatchData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.processbatchdata.aspx) with [Display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms416599.aspx) method - is available in SP Foundation but is very complicated as it's very complex.